# match word not capitalized a certain way

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that matches all instances of "capitalizedExactlyThisWay" that are not capitalizedExactlyThisWay.

[image: Here is what I'm trying to do]

I created a function that finds the indexes of all case insensitive matches and then pushes the values back in [like this (JSBIN)](http://jsbin.com/peviri/1/edit)

But I would rather just say something like  `text.replace(regexp,"<highlight>$1</highlight>");`

Comment: Is it possible that your string contains many other words that start with `capitalized`, but are not followed by `exactlythisway` (with different capitalization)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` has a callback function too.

```
s = s.replace(reg1, function(m){
  if(m===word) return m;
  return '<highlight>'+m+'</highlight>';
});
```

Comment: I like this, it's simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

If you could somehow get JavaScript to work with partial case-insensitive matching, i.e. `(?i)`, you could use the following expression:

```
capitalized(?!ExactlyThisWay)(?i)exactlythisway
```

If not, you're probably stuck with something like this:

```
capitalized(?!ExactlyThisWay)[a-zA-Z]+
```

The downside is that it will also match other variations such as `capitalizedfoobar` etc.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bN3xL2/1)

Comment: but sir it will match : capitalizedfoobar and capitalizedzoobaz

Comment: almost had it there but aelor is right :(  http://regex101.com/r/bN3xL2/6 http://jsbin.com/kutiwomo/1/edit +1 for  the negative lookahead

Comment: @Shanimal: What are you trying to accomplish? Your ultimate goal? Maybe there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: @Amal. the goal is more about tools in the toolchest and satisfying curiosity. In tis case I needed a regexp for my ide, but then I realized I could just search and replace using the appropriate case for both fields. and of course, at that moment it struck me that I had been at work too long. :) More just wondering if it could be done.

Comment: It would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex to match all the case-insensitive `exactlythisway` string but not of `ExactlyThisWay` ,

```
\bcapitalized(?!ExactlyThisWay)(?:[Ee][Xx][Aa][Cc][Tt][Ll][Yy][Tt][Hh][Ii][Ss][Ww][Aa][Yy])\b
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN3xL2/5)

Comment: oops javascript is complaining :P

Comment: I think OP want to get all the rest possible capitalizations that not match "capitalizedExactlyThisWay". So this variant is not so good for it. I'm not sure if it is really possible to do that with a regex.

Comment: good question, your upvote is mine. sabotage? shouldn't there be a rule that you can't vote on any topic that you've answered on?

Comment: yeah, im baffled as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JavaScript regular expressions do not support making only a part of the expression case-insensitive.

You could write a little helper function that does the dirty work:

```
function capitalizationSensitiveRegex(word) {
  var chars = word.split(""), i;

  for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    chars[i] = "[" + chars[i].toLowerCase() + chars[i].toUpperCase() + "]";
  }

  return new RegExp("(?=\\b" + chars.join("") + "\\b)(?!" + word + ").{" + word.length + "}", "g");
}
```

Result:

```
capitalizationSensitiveRegex("capitalizedExactlyThisWay");

=> /(?=\b[cC][aA][pP][iI][tT][aA][lL][iI][zZ][eE][dD][eE][xX][aA][cC][tT][lL][yY][tT][hH][iI][sS][wW][aA][yY]\b)(?!capitalizedExactlyThisWay).{25}/g
```

Note that this assumes ASCII letters due to limitations of how `\b` works in JavaScript. It also assumes you're not using any regex meta characters in `word` (brackets, backslashes, parentheses, stars, dots, etc). An extra step of regex-quoting each `char` is necessary to make the above stable.

Comment: I think everyone on this thread except Fabricator and anubhava got downvoted, wth? I call foul!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` and `map` method with a **callback**:

```
tok=[], input.match(/\bcapitalizedexactlythisway\b/ig).map( function (m) {
     if (m!="capitalizedExactlyThisWay") tok.push(m); });

console.log( tok );
["capitalizedEXACTLYTHISWAY", "capitalizedexactlYthisWay", "capitalizedexactlythisway"]
```

Comment: Isn't `reduce` used for reducing array to a single value.

Comment: yes right, instead of declaring tok as an array, you could declare the array anonymously as initialValue so `var tok = input.match...` (initialValue as in replace `map` with `reduce` and add [] as the second parameter)

Comment: Yes sure that can be done. I am using mobile at present so won't be able to test and edit the code. Feel free to edit this answer if you like.

Comment: ugh, `match` sometimes returns null and `null.reduce` / `null.map` are `not a function` :( To chain it we'd have to wrap it in something like `(haystack.match(re) || []).reduce...` http://jsbin.com/budexu/1/edit

Comment: Yes that is true `|| []` will need to be added to safeguard against null value.